# Prove $P(\mathbb{N}\setminus \left \{ 6 \right \})$~$P(\mathbb{N})\setminus P(\left \{ 6 \right \})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Prove: $P(\mathbb{N}\setminus \left \{ 6 \right \})$~$P(\mathbb{N})\setminus P(\left \{ 6 \right \})$

I want to prove it while finding two injective function, I have found a function to prove that:

$|P(\mathbb{N}\setminus \left \{ 6 \right \})| \le |P(\mathbb{N})\setminus P(\left \{ 6 \right \})|$

But I struggle to find a function to the other side, to show that
$|P(\mathbb{N})\setminus P(\left \{ 6 \right \})| \le |P(\mathbb{N}\setminus \left \{ 6 \right \})|$.

The best I did is finding this: $$g(A)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\emptyset & A=\left \{ 0,6 \right \} \\ 
A & 6 \notin A
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: How about $g(A) = \{h(a)~:~a\in A\}$ where $h(a)=\begin{cases}a&\text{if }a\leq 5\\ a+1&\text{if }a\geq 6\end{cases}$ so for instance $g(\{1,3\})=\{1,3\}$ while $g(\{4,5,6,7\})=\{4,5,7,8\}$

Comment: A function inside a function - nice! I didn't think about it at all. Thank you!

Comment: What about $\emptyset$ in this case?

Comment: "*What about $g(\emptyset)$ in this case?*"  Undefined since it isn't in the domain.  You might be able to massage the example to give a bijection if you were so inclined as well.  Letting $\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\dots\}$, from $P(\Bbb N)\setminus P(\{6\})$ to $P(\Bbb N\setminus \{6\})$ we could have $g(A) = \begin{cases}\emptyset&\text{if }A=\{1\}\\ \{a-1\}&\text{if }A=\{a\}~\text{and}~2\leq a\leq 5\\ \{a\}&\text{if }A=\{a\}~\text{and }7\leq a\\ h(A)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ where $h(A)$ is defined as above.

Comment: I'm sorry I wanted to ask about $\emptyset$ not $g(\emptyset)$

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you - I like your way of thinking!